# Grammatik in „In 2010, dem Jahr, in welchem ...“

Tags: style, time

Aus dem *Spiegel*:

> In 2010, dem Jahr, in welchem das Kanzleramt nachweislich vom … erfuhr, war Ernst Uhrlau bereits seit fünf Jahren Präsident …

Ist dieser Satz grammatikalisch richtig? Normalerweise gilt

> In 2010 war Ernst Uhrlau bereits …

als falsch. Dass es hier auch einen Relativsatz gibt, ändert nichts an dem Grammatik vom Hauptsatz. Wenn der Satz tatsächlich falsch ist, wie kann man ihn umschreiben?

Comment: Im Englischen ist es üblich, "in the year ..." zu "in ..." abzukürzen. Im Deutschen ist das eigentlich (noch) nicht üblich - wohl auch deshalb, weil "im Jahr" eine Silbe kürzer und deshalb weniger umständlich ist. Der starke Einfluss des Englischen dürfte diesen Prozess beschleunigen. Momentan ist das so aber noch falsch, auch wenn man es vor allem im Berufsleben gelegentlich schon liest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Oh ja, der Satz ist nicht schön. Ich biete:

> **Im Jahr** 2010, *als* das Kanzleramt nachweislich davon erfuhr, war Ernst Uhrlau bereits seit fünf Jahren Präsident.

[Der Zwiebelfisch](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-in-2010-im-jahre-2010-a-311727.html) hat die Konstruktion *in + Jahreszahl* bereits erschöpfend auseinandergenommen. Oder ging es dir gar um ganz etwas anderes?

Comment: @Downvoter: Was ist an meiner Antwort **falsch**? Ich habe bewusst *nicht schön* und nicht *unrichtig* oder *falsch* geschrieben. Der Quellensatz hakt an mehreren Stellen, nur eine davon ist *in 2010*.

Answer (score 6):

Tja, falsch ist wieder so ein starkes Wort. Wenn man nicht *in 2010* sagen will, was bei vielen als stilistisch unschön gilt, kann man es sehr leicht anders formulieren:

> Im Jahr 2010, in dem das Kanzleramt … erfuhr, war Ernst Uhrlau bereits seit fünf Jahren Präsident …
>
> 2010, in dem Jahr, in dem das Kanzleramt …
>
> Als das Kanzleramt … erfuhr, nämlich 2010, war Ernst Uhrlau …
>
> Das Kanzleramt erfuhr 2010 …. Zu dieser Zeit war Ernst Uhrlau …

Answer (score 1):

"In 2010" ist deshalb falsch, weil die Präposition "in" im Sinne von innerhalb in einem zeitlichen Zusammenhang korrekterweise mit Dativ stehen muss. Benutzt man die Präposition, müsste man die Phrase zu "im Jahr 2010" ergänzen.

Benutzt man für das Jahr keinen Artikel, sondern nur die reine Jahreszahl, dann ist die Jahreszahl an sich schon eine adverbiale Bestimmung der Zeit, und die Präposition "in" ist überflüssig.

Der Satz würde also korrekter Weise heißen:

"2010, im Jahr, ..." wie bereits oben beschrieben.

Ich könnte mir vorstellen, dass das "unangenehme Aufstoßen" dieser Redewendung, welches bereits mehrfach angeführt wurde, einfach darauf zurückzuführen ist, dass diese Verwendungsweise etablierte durchgängige Muster im Sprachgefühl der Muttersprachler verletzt und noch dazu ineffizienter als die natürliche (überkommene) Ausdrucksweise für den gleichen Inhalt ist.

Answer (score -3):

Es ist eine sich immer stärker verbreitende und allgemein verständliche Formulierung. Damit erfüllt sie wohl die Grundanforderungen für „grammatikalisch richtig“, was auch immer das konkret heißen mag. 
Eine Grammatik des Deutschen, die *in* + Jahreszahl nicht als regelgerecht beschreibt, ist entweder veraltet oder auf bestimmte Register und Varietäten beschränkt, die weder Wirtschaftsdeutsch noch Politikdeutsch noch Journalismusdeutsch einschließen.

Wie fast jede sprachliche Neuerung stößt auch diese auf Ablehnung und Kritik. Es gibt viele Möchtegernbesserwisser und Sprachnörgler vom Schlage eines Bastian Sick, die sich auf solche veralteten oder beschränkten Grammatiken versteifen und die *in*-Konstruktion daher als „falsch“ bezeichnen. Die haben leider Sprache nicht verstanden – immerhin bezeichnet der Autor seine buchgewordene Kolumne „Zwiebelfisch“ selbst eher als unterhaltend denn als linguistisch und weicht damit fundierter Kritik wie der von André Meinunger aus.

Manche nennen das Muster nicht gleich „grammatikalisch falsch“, sondern nur „stilistisch unschön“. (Mir persönlich stößt es auch immer noch unangenehm auf.) Das ist aber meist ein reines Gewohnheitsurteil (also mit absehbarer Verfallszeit) und für die oben genannten Ausprägungen der Publizistiksprache kann das Konstrukt in 2015  schon nicht mehr als markiert gelten.

Comment: Ich weiß nicht, was die Leute haben, aber ich finde deine Antwort trifft die Sache auf den Kern.

Comment: @Takkat Jetzt nach dem Edit schon. Davor mE nicht. Downvote zurückgezogen.